# Change content of the button on mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf

The style of `button` is predefined `Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"` is it possible to change content of such `button` when the mouse is over it? I just dlike to put a custom control in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style to your button.

```
<Button>
  <Button.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="" Value="" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </Button.Style>
```

Set your property in `Setter` and `Value`

Add `<Style BasedOn="Give your default Style here">` to keep your predefined style.

Comment: This is brilliant solution but  Error: Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'IFrameworkInputElement'.

Comment: Thanks i have added that to the answer.