# How do I make a tooltip displayw hen mouse cursor is over button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouse

How can I make a tooltip appear when a button is hovered over with the mouse in WPF?

Comment: Use style to do that [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32483665/2470362)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change content of the button on mouseover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483610/change-content-of-the-button-on-mouseover)

Comment: Yes, a tooltip. Sorry, I didn't know the word in english.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <Button ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000" 
    ToolTipService.ShowDuration="2000" 
    ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="10000" 
    ToolTip="This is a tool tip." />
```

Answer (score 1):

"ToolTip" is the property that needs to be set for adding text to controls that are actively being hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 events: PointerEntered and PointerExited, draw content for button and **give a name** to content (or to it's template)

Xaml:

```
<Button PointerEntered="Button_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Button_PointerExited" >
      <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock1" Text="not hovering" />
      </Button.Content>
 </Button>
```

on code behind you handle those events:

```
private void Button_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtBlock1.Text = "hovering";
}

private void Button_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtBlock1.Text = "not hovering";
}
```